# C statement const meanings

Tags: c, syntax, constants

In the code below, what do the first and second `const` mean?

I guess first or second means `foo` is constant; the other one means elements of `foo` are also constants. Is it true?

```
static const char * const foo[] = {"bar", "baz"};
```

Comment: [Required reading](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html).

Comment: I also tried: const static const const char * const foo[] = {"bar", "baz"}; and compiled without problems with gcc. I think the compiler ignores the extra const's.

Comment: interesting you can add as many as you want
<pre>
static const const const char * const const foo[] = {"bar", "baz"};
</pre>
gcc gives nor error neither warning even with -Wall -Wextra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means its an array of const pointers (so you can't change the pointers) to const chars (so you can't change the chars via the pointers). This is a common way of defining fixed strings, such as command names, in an application.

Answer (score 3):

See [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+char+%2a+const+foo%5B%5D):

`declare foo as array of const pointer to const char`